# Expect script to change default password

Tags: expect, change-password

I'm trying to build a simple Expect script to change the default password.  Our admin forces us to change passwords immediately after deploying a new system in our cloud infrastructure.  I want to build an Expect script because I have to do this across a few dozen systems.

The prompts look like this:

```
❯ ssh root@mysystem.company.com
root@mysystem.company.com's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)
Last login: Tue Aug 23 12:14:58 2022 from 10.123.45.67
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user root.
New password: 
Retype new password:
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
Connection to mysystem.company.com closed.
```

My expect script looks like this:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/expect -f

set timeout 60

set user [lindex $argv 0]
set host [lindex $argv 1]
set old [lindex $argv 2]
set new [lindex $argv 3]

spawn -noecho ssh -q -o StrictHostKeychecking=no "$user\@$host"

expect "password:"
send "$old\r"
expect "New password"
send "$new\r"
expect "Retype new password:"
send "$new\r"
```

That 1st expect statement is working, but I cannot figure out why the 2nd expect statement isn't working:

```
❯ expect spawn root mysystem.company.com oldPassword newPassword
root@mysystem.company.com's password: 
You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)
Last login: Tue Aug 23 13:14:12 2022 from 10.123.45.67
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user root.
New password: %
```

It immediately exits from the script once it reaches `New password:`.  I've tried various things but not figuring this out.

Please help!

---

It was suggested to re-run with -d (debug) enabled.  The output appears to show its working as expected (no pun intended), but the password wasn't actually changed.  When I attempt to login, I'm prompted through the same steps.  Maybe someone else can help interpret this output:

```
❯ expect -d spawn root mysystem.company.com lgmPjgY2xTJH 73a40HpVCgRey9fP
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = spawn  argv[3] = root  argv[4] = mysystem.company.com  argv[5] = lgmPjgY2xTJH  argv[6] = 73a40HpVCgRey9fP
set argc 4
set argv0 "spawn"
set argv "root mysystem.company.com lgmPjgY2xTJH 73a40HpVCgRey9fP"
executing commands from command file spawn
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {10930}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "password:"? no

expect: does "\r" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "password:"? no
root@mysystem.company.com's password:
expect: does "\rroot@mysystem.company.com's password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "password:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\rroot@mysystem.company.com's password:"
send: sending "lgmPjgY2xTJH\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "New password"? no


expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "New password"? no
You are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)
Last login: Wed Aug 24 20:01:38 2022 from 10.123.45.678
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!

expect: does " \r\nYou are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)\r\nLast login: Wed Aug 24 20:01:38 2022 from 10.123.45.678\r\r\nWARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "New password"? no
Changing password for user root.

expect: does " \r\nYou are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)\r\nLast login: Wed Aug 24 20:01:38 2022 from 10.123.45.678\r\r\nWARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\nChanging password for user root.\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "New password"? no
New password:
expect: does " \r\nYou are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)\r\nLast login: Wed Aug 24 20:01:38 2022 from 10.123.45.678\r\r\nWARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\nChanging password for user root.\r\nNew password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "New password"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "New password"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\nYou are required to change your password immediately (administrator enforced)\r\nLast login: Wed Aug 24 20:01:38 2022 from 10.123.45.678\r\r\nWARNING: Your password has expired.\r\nYou must change your password now and login again!\r\nChanging password for user root.\r\nNew password"
send: sending "73a40HpVCgRey9fP\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does ": " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Retype new password:"? no


expect: does ": \r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Retype new password:"? no
Retype new password:
expect: does ": \r\nRetype new password: " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "Retype new password:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Retype new password:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ": \r\nRetype new password:"
send: sending "73a40HpVCgRey9fP\r" to { exp6 }
❯ echo $?
0
```

Comment: `expect -d /your/script.exp` and see what's happening.

Comment: thx for the tip, i just posted the results above. unfortunately it doesn't help me, maybe i'm not interpreting it right

Comment: according to the `expect -d` output, the script stopped after sending the password for the `Retype new password:` prompt. so just add `expect eof` at the end of your script. this is the most common mistake when using Expect. you must wait for the spawned program to finish.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells  this worked!  brilliant!  thx so much.  we can submit this as the answer... do you want the honor?  if not, i can do it.

Comment: feel free to post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the expect -d output, the script stopped after sending the password for the `Retype new password:` prompt.

So just add `expect eof` at the end of the script.

This is the most common mistake when using Expect.  You must wait for the spawned program to finish.

(credit goes to @sexpect)